# Help me understand why this question is not focused enough

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, post-ban, reputation-bias

Need help understanding why this was flagged as not focused enough:

[How do I map a url to a specific folder in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498085/how-do-i-map-a-url-to-a-specific-folder-in-apache)

The question got closed for lacking focus and my ask privileges were revoked despite the fact that it got 2 answers both with upvotes which presumably mean they were helpful to people.

The way I see it is I got punished for my question which led to answers that actually were helpful.

Comment: Many users refuse to explain their downvotes, as they've found that doing so is often met with verbal abuse, harassment, revenge downvotes, or a simple flat denial that the problems they mentioned exist. Regarding the question itself, note that question bans are never the result of one single question, but a consistent pattern of poorly-received questions. You almost certainly have multiple questions that have been deleted, and those would have gotten you close to the question ban; the most recent one is merely the one that tipped you over the edge.

Comment: You've actually asked at least two more questions since the linked question, 3 months apart from one another so that is most certainly *not* the one that triggered the question ban (which restricts you to one every 6 months).

Comment: I only posted 6 or 7 times, only deleted a couple one of which was a dupe. 4 remain and this is the only one with a neg

Comment: Forget the ban, question still remains, why is this one closed?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not enough of a subject matter expert to weigh in on that.

Comment: Please see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr) for details on why people are not required to explain their downvotes.

Comment: If you're demanding that people explain their downvotes, why aren't you also demanding why they explain their upvotes?

Comment: I don't need explanations for downvotes, but it would be nice to get some feed back other than a "-1"

Comment: I would like upvotes to accompany a comment or answer, those are more useful than simply +1 or -1

Comment: I was asking a legitimate question as to why the original post was considered not focused and closed, getting -1 -1 -1 -1 doesn't help me.

Comment: I downvoted mostly because the tone of the question is overly hostile; for example, the title implicitly accuses people who voted to close of bias. That makes it seem more like an opportunity to rant than a legitimate request for feedback on the question. (I don't have enough domain knowledge to know whether the specific question you refer to is overly broad or not, so I've refrained from voting either way on the question itself).

Comment: I put "SO Biased" because my question got downvoted and closed, but an answer given by a user with a high rep got upvoted. How is it that an answer by someone with high rep is praised but the question that led to that answer was punished?

Comment: @ihatzi, comments and votes are for different goals. Discussing them under this question has no actual purpose. Please stop. If you want to discuss their relation, I believe you still can ask more questions on meta, but I wouldn't recommend to: they are not well received.

Comment: BTW: my original question "Help me understand why this question is not focused enough"

Comment: "How is it that an answer by someone with high rep is praised but the question that led to that answer was punished?" Sometimes a low-quality question can have a high-quality answer, irrespective of the rep counts of the question-asker and answerer.

Comment: Was it a low quality question?

Comment: Hmm, one unpleasant thing not mentioned in question itself (because OP doesn't see this): one of answer authors has also casted VTC. Feels rather disingenuous.

Comment: eh, depends on timing. and what they actually gave as the vote reason. Since the timeline only shows the resulting reason, that's all we get.

Comment: @KevinB, right, forgot that their reason may differ. Sorry for disingenuous part of my previous comment. But it still will be interesting to here their opinion.

Comment: "At least if your going to down vote tell me why?" - Possibly because you are asking us to explain the actions of three specific people made over a year ago, and then poisoning the well by assuming (in the title and tags) that those actions must have reflected some form of "bias"?

Comment: @Karl, I meant if you are downvoting this post, not the original one. And I didn't mean explain the vote, but help me by answering the question I posed here. these "-1" don't help me understand how to pose better questions in the first place. And the Bias part was because high rep people who answered got upvotes, but my original question got downvoted and closed. Was this just a  case of terrible question, but fantastic helpful answers? And how is that even possible if the answer wouldn't exist without the question?

Comment: "I meant if you are downvoting this post, not the original one." Yes, I understood that completely. Which is why I explained why I am downvoting this post, rather than the original one, by referring to things that you did in this post, not the original one.

Comment: You know, when you smack someone, it helps to tell them why they got smacked. Helps improve behavior in the future than just the smack alone.

Comment: Oh, don't be so melodramatic. No-one's smacking anyone.

Comment: Sure does feel like a smack!

Comment: On this Question, I can assure you that *Help me understand why this question is not focused enough* would have been seen much more favorably by the community than *SO Biased : Help me understand why this question is not focused enough*. on the Question in question I don't know the technology or tools well enough to comment on its quality., but as a general note, It's fuzzy on what went wrong and what you've tried to resolve the problem. That would be Needs Details rather than Needs Focus, but still at risk of being closed.

Comment: What exactly about the closure of that question makes Stack Overflow biased? That’s a serious suggestion and powerful word. Calling the community biased is one of many reasons users avoid explaining their downvotes. Your edits made the question eligible to be reopened you will have to wait till that review process is completed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: PMJI, but I think the OP's question seemed more like a "Needs Clarity.." rather than "Needs focus"..  fwiw.

Comment: Great, this meta-question is now closed and the question in question is now deleted! This is just compounding my increasing dislike of this "community".

Comment: ... and the OP suspended?!

Comment: @MrWhite, could [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425644) be related to suspension?

Answer (score 7):

I can see where the close voters are perhaps coming from**<sup>*1</sup>**, although it would arguably be "Needs details or clarity", rather than "Needs more focus" (the final "reason" given is not necessarily unanimous).

I did not cast a close vote myself but attempted to seek clarification at the time in comments below the question, but my questions went unanswered. (My questions could have been better, but it was a start.) Had I returned to the question later then a close vote would have been warranted, but there was no further activity on the question (or answers) until now(!?) so I did not get notified.

You've also not given any code sample(s), either what you have tried (not necessarily a close reason in itself IMO, although many would think so) or the contents of your existing `.htaccess` file, which is arguably more important to reach a solution. (Conflicts with existing directives are a common cause of error.)

Whilst on the face of it, your question looks like a relatively "simple" rewrite, you've not actually stated what the intended target/response is, which makes this impossible to answer succinctly. The devil is in the detail.

[@CBroe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71498279/369434) does *exactly* what you are asking (the regex is spot on), but this is also why it cannot work**<sup>*2</sup>**. It is not "accepted", so I assume it doesn't, but why have you not tried to troubleshoot this in comments?

What is `/users/j/o/h/john`? "on the server the folder would be in..." ("in" or "at"?) would seem to imply it is a filesystem directory (although I'm not entirely convinced). However, if it is a directory then the target MUST end in a trailing slash, but you have omitted the trailing slash throughout the question. (If you omit the trailing slash then mod_dir will trigger an external redirect to append the trailing slash and the underlying filesystem directory is exposed.) But if it is a directory, what are you expecting to be served? Apache does not serve directories, it serves files. Perhaps the intention is to serve the `DirectoryIndex` document from that directory? But if that's the case then you should be rewriting directly to the document and cut out the middle man (mod_dir).

I asked in comments, "Are you intending to access files from this subdirectory?". If you are then you will likely need a different rewrite to handle this (or risk exposing the filesystem directory). But if not then why is it a directory and not a simple file (eg. `john.html`)?

If `/users/j/o/h/john` is not a physical directory (ie. `/users/j/o/h/` is the directory and `john` is some resource that needs to be served or passed to a front-controller), then this is not going to work. (But you make reference to a front-controller in [comments on the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498085/how-do-i-map-a-url-to-a-specific-folder-in-apache#comment126371158_71498242)?)

---

<sup>***1** Although whether they are really voting for the reasons I've outlined here is another matter.</sup>

<sup>***2** Although it is missing the `L` (or `END`) flag so could also result in a conflict with later directives.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The version of the question which was closed doesn't include your recent edits mentioning that you were trying to get  RegexRule working. You just said:

> Is this possible with .htaccess or some other Apache method?

I didn't vote on the question, but I can see that that general question could be seen as unfocused.

Answer (score -10):

It is ridiculous that your question was closed as "needs more focus". It asks one very specific and answerable question.

Whether it's on-topic: there are [almost 73,000 .htaccess questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess), you're not gonna convince me that someone suddenly decided that Apache configuration is off-topic. Web servers *are* software commonly used by developers and I'm tired of (people) pretending it's not.

If people want .htaccess questions gone, they should put in the leg work and have the tag updated and banned. Until then, do not abuse incorrect close vote reasons. I'm so done with that.

Comment: Not to mention that this also involves REGEX

Comment: _"Not to mention that this also involves REGEX"_ - my bad, in that case I support it being obliterated.

Comment: Note that the existence of previous similar questions are meaningless, as many of them were asked before other sites were created. For instance, Apache configuration questions may be more suitable now for [webmasters.se]  or [sf] than SO. Not saying that's necessarily the case here, but justifying asking a question based on the fact others like it have been asked before is invalid logic.

Comment: Don't like REGEX?

Comment: @Ken we either accept such questions or we don't, we've been in limbo for a decade already. I find the arbitrary distinction extremely annoying and unproductive, but if someone wants .htaccess questions gone to either of those sites, ban the tag already. Then still, using the wrong close-vote should be a suspendable offense. Even if the close-voters believed .htaccess to be off-topic, they should say so and not pick a random reason.

Comment: @ihatzi no, I do not like the RegEx tag for multiple reasons.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry for dragging you into this, you keep getting -1's too now.

Comment: @ihatzi me when I'm getting downvoted: https://thumbs.gfycat.com/SelfreliantDeterminedHeron-size_restricted.gif

Comment: Downvotes really suck when starting out on this site. Makes it really hard to get any traction at all. Not to mention find answers to your questions.

Comment: Agree that it is closed for the wrong reason. Disagree that it is on-topic on SO. If we apply this standard for "tools commonly used by programmers", then word, powerpoint and SAP questions are also on topic.

Comment: Are .htaccess questions not supposed to be posted on SO?

Comment: eh, it depends. See the relevant tag wikis. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache

Comment: @ihatzi: I consider .htaccess questions as off-topic for SO unless they directly involve writing some code and the problem is in the code part. Everything else is server configuration (and the task of a server admin, not a developer) and should be asked on ServerFault.

Comment: Says " Use this tag if and only if .htaccess content is directly involved in the topic. We know many people are using .htaccess, but kindly ask the members of the community to not use this tag, unless you know it is on-topic in your question."

I think this was the right place for it then, no?

Comment: there's more to it than that, it suggests viewing the apache wiki for on-topicness of questions. .htaccess *is* part of configuring httpd, and therefore isn't directly a programming question on it's own.

Comment: @BDL, wouldn't this basically be a REGEX solution? Wouldn't that make it appropriate? RewriteRule's are generally REGEXs

Comment: regex is special, in a particularly unfortunate way. While it's relatively useless as a tag on it's own, and most questions related to regex are absurdly useless, regex, as it is typically used on SO, is being used in a programming-related way where as .htaccess is literally a config file. regex *can also* be used in a config file, but that doesn't make all cases of using regex off topic

Comment: @ihatzi: I have no clue how the solution to your problem looks like. In general, no, the fact that it could involve regex is not enough to make it a programming problem. But the policy for regex is very fuzzy. There are a lot of rep farmers (even with very high rep) on that tag who basically answer anything as if they are regex101 themselves. The only good reason (for me) that the regex tag exists is that you can blacklist all of these questions.

Comment: So they should do away with the .htaccess tag if inappropriate here.

Comment: I started a new topic just for this : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425615/is-the-so-htaccess-tag-off-topic-and-should-it-be-removed

Comment: If weather or not .htacces is on-topic is such a hot topic issue, then why is this posting getting so little action : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425615/is-the-so-htaccess-tag-off-topic-and-should-it-be-removed

Comment: Or is this not really the issue?

Comment: @CodeCaster: That's nonsense. Many tags exist for historical reasons, because highly upvoted historical questions were tagged with them. Consider all the computer hardware or OS questions that were asked before SU was created, for example. We don't delete the tags just because the new site was created - the questions stay here because they have a lot of links to them scattered around, and deleting them would invalidate all of those links. There are also many existing tags that start with **DO NOT USE THIS TAG. Instead, use...** (to be continued)

Comment: or directions to post to other sites under certain conditions (see the [tag:kubernetes] tag wiki for one example where some questions are appropriate here and others belong at [sf]).

Comment: @Ken I really don't care about this gatekeeping, and I don't agree with it. Are you saying all 400 k8s questions asked this month fulfill the criteria of the tag? There are so many tags saying one should NOT USE them. If it's somehow development-related, I won't close-vote as off-topic. I had a comment posted that I would go down the rabbit hole of the .htaccess tag and I now regret removing that comment and incorporating it in the answer. All of that distracts from the issue at hand though, where people are abusing their closevotes.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, that's clearly not what I'm saying, and I made that clear. My whole commentary has been about your blanket assertion that existing questions on a tag automatically make all other questions related to that tag acceptable. My polnt is that they do not. Existence of a tag or previous question are meaningless. Guidelines evolve over time, and new sites are created (although not as frequently now). The only thing that matter are the guidelines **on the specific date that a question is being asked**. (continued)

Comment: I specifically cited the [tag:kubernetes] tag as a **specific example** of a tag that has some questions that are acceptable here and others that are not and should be asked at a different site ([sf]). A very large percentage of questions using that tag today (and yesterday, and last week) violate the site guidelines, as indicated by that specific tag wiki description and the **ALL CAPS** note it contains. *Gatekeeping* (enforcing the guidelines by keeping off-topic questions away) is part of what keeps noise and clutter down here, and is necessary whether you agree or not.

Comment: I wholly support the notion to just make it idiot proof. Either allow all questions or no questions. This wishy washy "some are allowed in and some aren't" is just chaos and an invitation for people to start creatively interpreting the site rules just to be able to nuke what they don't like from orbit.