# Is the SO .htaccess tag off topic and should it be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request, scope

After a lot of chatter about [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) questions being off topic on Stack Overflow, I wanted to pose the question....

Should the [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) tag be removed?

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   Yes, the concept is quite well defined and it is very specific file
   with specific format and usage (config for Apache servers).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   While general "webserver configuration" is off-topic on Stack Overflow, there
   are large number of questions involving .htaccess file that are
   on-topic. So by itself it is not indication of being off-topic. Also
   guidance explicitly written out in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.htaccess/info).
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   Likely, there are usually multiple ways to configure web
   servers/deal with code issues coming out of misconfigurations -
   adding .htaccess achieves "would like to get answers involving that
   file"/"likely caused by .htaccess" which is useful.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Absolutely.

Several people suggested this in my posting : [SO Biased : Help me understand why this question is not focused enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425613/so-biased-help-me-understand-why-this-question-is-not-focused-enough)

Lets vote on it!

Comment: Perhaps someone should add one answer to the effect of "yes", and another one to the effect of "no" so that it's clear what upvotes indicate? I upvoted because it seems to make sense to have a post on the topic, but right now it's a little unclear what upvotes indicate.

Comment: I guess will have to judge by the up vs down votes. Up is get rid of it, Down is keep it.

Comment: If we're voting if to get rid of it or not, then shouldn't this be formatted as a [[meta-tag:burninate-request]]?

Comment: Just adding the tag doesn't make it a [[meta-tag:burninate-request]]; there is a [process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).

Comment: Oh, didnt realize.

Comment: @ThomA The OP isn't making a request to burninate it - they're asking whether or not people want the tag. I guess if people want it removed the next step would be a burninate request (which is admittedly a slightly awkward step). That would probably not be able to advance until after the moderation strike ends, though, since most of the people that actually perform that function are on strike.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine and a burnination request is a great way to guage if it should go. Why add a extra "should we" step? Just start with the formal request.

Comment: ihatzi I'm not sure why you ignored @ThomA comment about the process - I've added burnination criteria for you to the post - feel free to edit as you see fit (also I have hard time understanding why that tag is so off-topic that 70K+ questions need to be reviewed)

Comment: Yea, this tag doesn't even come close to qualifying for burnination. I think you took one user's dislike of the tag a little too seriously.

Comment: `.htaccess` is one of those tags that I see on `php` questions, then immediately ignore (since I know next to nothing about how it actually works). I then inevitably circle back to to find that someone has provided an answer that perfectly solves the question, typically by modifying said `.htaccess` file. That, in and of itself, seems like a good enough reason for me for this tag to avoid burnination.

Comment: Is this *really* the hill you are willing to die on? There are so many more other completely worthless tags that should be removed that would actually be a net gain for the site/community. This is a hard "No" from me.

Comment: *If* (and it's a big ***if***) the tag were deemed to qualify where would many of these questions "go"? As mentioned there's over 70,000 questions for the tag and though some are probably mistags, and some just bad questions, many provide a good amount of **helpful** and **useful** information and it *is* about the `.htaccess` file; for this to even be considered I think we'd need to work out if there's a community better suited for the questions. [Webmasters.se] maybe? I know nothing about the community or the tag, so I have no idea.

Comment: From the four criteria that you listed in your question, it looks like we should keep it. To paraphrase what you wrote: 1. Yes, it's well-defined and specific, 2. By itself it's not an indication for being off-topic, 3. It achieves something useful and 4. Absolutely, it means the same thing in all contexts. So to me this seems to be a clear indication that it should *not* be burninated.

Answer (score -2):

Since my comments probably caused this question, here's my (rather extreme) point of view:

All questions about configuring some server system are (or should be) off-topic unless they directly involve writing some code or the tool is exclusively used for development work (like configuring a compiler or IDE). All questions about tasks that are usually done by Server Admins should be asked on Server Fault.

There are a few gray areas like Docker, but everything related to configuring Apache, ISS, MySQL, ... should not be asked on Stack Overflow.

Burninating these tags is probably too much work (70k questions on [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) are too much to handle), so I would for now only add a warning to the tag and close new questions but leave old questions as they are.

Comment: Why? I don't want to have to visit Stack Overflow, DBA, Server Fault, Webmasters _and_ Super User when all I'm doing is getting my SQL-connected TLS-certified web app online in my dev environment. I find this distinction utterly pointless.

Comment: Yea, no. .htaccess rules are basically code. The tag clearly does not qualify for burnination. A user's dislike of a tag is not valid ground for it to be "censored" like that.

Comment: @CodeCaster: C++ and OpenGL is what I've been teaching for a decade at university. Nowadays I'm developing 50% web stuff with C#/ISS/Azure and the other 50% are optimizing numerical simulation code. But why make that about me?

Comment: Ok, but can you explain _why_ you think _"everything related to configuring Apache, ISS, MySQL, ... should not be asked on Stack Overflow"_? You can't just like state that as a fact, you know?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Because there exists a specialized site for these questions. Imho it's better to have everything in one place instead of having it split over several communities. If there is a community consensus that server configuration questions are also on-topic on SO, that's also fine for me.

Comment: The vast majority of `.htaccess` questions are part of the "application code", they are not "configuring the web server". The ability to configure Apache using `.htaccess` is very limited. If you were to burninate `.htaccess` then you would need to also burn the related tags `mod-rewrite`, `mod-alias`, etc. which would be very silly.

Answer (score -7):

### No, it should not be burninated.

---

Here's a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425615/is-the-so-htaccess-tag-off-topic-and-should-it-be-removed/425619#comment965985_425615) from EJoshuaS:

> Perhaps someone should add one answer to the effect of "yes", and another one to the effect of "no" so that it's clear what upvotes indicate? I upvoted because it seems to make sense to have a post on the topic, but right now it's a little unclear what upvotes indicate.

This one will be the "No" answer. Upvote this answer if you think it is on-topic for this site.

Comment: These answers are irrelevant. The tag doesn't come close to qualifying for burnination.

Comment: If you're going to do this (which isn't necessarily a good idea here), then make the answers **really clear**. That means stating the position in a header on the first line. In other words, have the first line be Markdown like `## Yes, the [tag:.htaccess] tag is off-topic and should be removed` or `## No, the [tag:.htaccess] tag is on-topic and should NOT be removed`. As these are, someone has to read nearly to the end of the "answer" to know what they would be voting on, which wastes a lot of time and results in fewer people voting for the position and some down-voting due to lack of clarity.

Comment: @Makyen Point taken. I think I saw this on another meta one time (I don't remember the meta question) and I thought it seemed to work out okay. That's the main reason I did this.

Answer (score -11):

### Yes, it should be burninated.

---

Here's a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425615/is-the-so-htaccess-tag-off-topic-and-should-it-be-removed/425619#comment965985_425615) from EJoshuaS:

> Perhaps someone should add one answer to the effect of "yes", and another one to the effect of "no" so that it's clear what upvotes indicate? I upvoted because it seems to make sense to have a post on the topic, but right now it's a little unclear what upvotes indicate.

This one will be the "Yes" answer. Upvote this answer if you think it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I like how both the no and yes variants are downvoted. There is no better way to show how divisive this topic is.

Comment: Well, "yes" is downvoted more, so I think over all that's a no.

Comment: @Gimby I downvoted _both_ these answers because they're not useful. The tag does not qualify for burnination. Removing tags is not a democratic choice that can just ignore existing processes.

Comment: @Cerbrus If the tag does not qualify for burnination, then why not upvote the answer that says don't burinate it? I don't understand your logic.

Comment: Because these answers are pointless, as there's absolutely no justification to start the burnination process.

Comment: It was a cute experiment though. Maybe not do this again in the future, it's kind of weird to have a perfectly functional yes/no voting system and then create yes/no posts to... vote yes or no on. My brain.